# an easier copy-assignment operator implement?

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer 5th,13.2.1 Class That Act Like Values，the author make a class that act like a value, which means each object have its own copy of the resource that the class manage.The class is below, It is a very simple class, just contain a pointer to a string, and an int, member function are just default constructor and copy-control member.

```
class HasPtr{
    public:
    HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string()) :ps(new std::string(s)), i(0){}
    HasPtr(const HasPtr &p) :ps(new std::string(*p.ps)), i(p.i){}
    HasPtr &operator=(const HasPtr &rhs);
    ~HasPtr(){ delete ps; }
    private:
        std::string *ps;
        int i;
};
```

Below is the implement of the operator= given by the book

```
HasPtr &HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs){
    auto newp = new std::string(*rhs.ps);
    delete ps;
    ps = newp;
    i = *rhs.i;
    return *this;
}
```

This is good, but i think that we can use the following implement which can avoid delete pointer and allocate new memory.

```
HasPtr &HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs){
    *ps = *rhs.ps;
    i = rhs.i;
    return *this;
}
```

I test my code works, even self-assignment.However, is there any problem with this code?

Comment: That works in this case because `*ps` is assignable. That isn't always the case.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I understand.It is because std::string defines the operator=, so it works. If the member doesn't define =, then i must use the implement given by the book.I think about this because the next chapter compare the performance of the library swap with the swap defined by the class.

Comment: What is the point of this? Why not just make string a non-pointer member?

Comment: @NeilKirk: The point is to learn how copy semantics work.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no problem in your code.

```
*ps
```

is itself a value type, so you can assign it directly. If you were making changes to improve the code, you might want to go further and change ps into a std::string instead of a std::string*. Then, you could eliminate the need for new and delete from the HasPtr class.

If

```
*ps
```

were instead a raw pointer to memory that class HasPtr manages, you would have to write code such as in the example from the book.

Comment: I just want to avoid the new/delete, so i don't want to write as the example.

Answer (score 0):

In your original example, you had copied the contents of *ps to itself, which is OK.  However as the comment to you suggested, this may not always be the case.

As to other solutions, here is one (maybe something like this will be explained later in your book):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
HasPtr &HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs)
{
    HasPtr temp(rhs);
    std::swap(ps, temp.ps);
    std::swap(i, temp.i);
    return *this;
}
```

This is the `copy/swap` idiom.  A temporary is created from `rhs`, and the internals of the temporary are swapped out with `this`'s members.  The temporary dies, at the end, taking along with it `this`'s former values.

Note that there is no explicit memory allocation, as you're relying on the copy constructor to create the temporary copy initially.  This means that this technique requires a working copy constructor, and a working destructor.  Once you have those in place, an assignment operator is very simple if done this way, as there is no real "grunt work" coding to do -- the copy constructor would handle it.

So is this easier than the book's version?  Depends on how you look at it -- the copy/swap can be used in almost every situation, where you basically only need to start off with working implementations of two of the three functions described in the "rule of 3", namely the copy constructor and destructor.  The assignment operator just comes along for the ride by taking advantage of the other two functions, plus perform simple swaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But first the compiler generated assignment operator will just copy the pointer, not the content that the pointer point to. Second my code won't cause memory leak, because the pointer owned by h2 always pointed to the same memory, i just change the content of the memory.

Comment: @TungWah I edited my post.  Yes, you're right, however as the other comment suggested, you got away with it because the object behined the pointer has built-in copy semantics.